# Error while trying to import bibliometrix results to biblioshiny

Tags: r

I am currently working on a bibliometric analysis using the `bibliometrix` package in R. After performing the analysis, I want to import the results into `bibliometrix::biblioshiny()` for visualization and exploration. However, I am encountering an error when trying to import the data.

```r
# Load necessary packages
library(bibliometrix)

# Import data into R
dados <- read.xlsx("/Users/sergionascimento/Google Drive/Meu Drive/000 - Uni9 (Doutorado)/Tese/Estudo 1 Necessidades/23072023/scopus.xlsx")

# Perform bibliometric analysis
resultados <- biblioAnalysis(dados)

# Save results in RData object
save(resultados, file = "resultados_bibliometrix.RData")

# Export data to Biblioshiny in XLSX format
write.xlsx(resultados, file = "/Users/sergionascimento/Google Drive/Meu Drive/000 - Uni9 (Doutorado)/Tese/Estudo 1 Necessidades/23072023/dados_biblioshiny.xlsx")
```

Comment: It's very difficult to help with the question as it's currently written. What line generated the error? What was the error? Can you provide some lines from that excel file? Have a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on improving your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What error are you encountering?  It's not obvious what the problem is. Also, you haven't given us a [mcve] ...